# Inheritance in .Net 3.5 from Framework 1 base classes. Can it be done?

Tags: .net

As far as I know you cannot run .NET 1.1 code and .NET 3.5 code in the same process as they do not use the same version of the CLR.

What are the implications of this for inheritance? I can imagine that you should be able to reference 1.1 assemblies from 3.5 code as the interfaces are well defined and the implementation can be in different CLR versions, but does this apply to inheritance and if it does then how?

Is it possible to have a base class derived from say System.Windows.Forms.Form, and implement some general functions therein which apply System.Data, etc., implement this base class in a version 1.1 assembly and then create a project targeted for Framework 3.5 and derive the main form class from this Version 1.1 base assembly?

If I try this I get the compiler error

> Error Message Value of type
>   '' cannot be converted to
>   ''. Type mismatch could be
>   due to mixing a file reference to
>   '' in project
>   '' with a file reference
>   to '' in project
>   '20_App_Code'. If both assemblies are
>   identical, try replacing these
>   references so both references are from
>   the same location."

Filepath 1 being System.Windows.Forms.dll for Framework 1 and Filepath 2 being System.Windows.Forms.dll for Framework 3.5 …

Clearly these assemblies are not “Identical” so I was expecting this not to work.

The strange thing is that in changing the reference in the 3.5 project to the 1.1 Assembly to a file (dll) reference it compiles and seems to run just fine. When investigating at runtime it seems to be executing the 1.1 base class in Framework 3.5, not loading framework 1.1 at all, which seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

>As far as I know you cannot run .NET 1.1 code and .NET 3.5 code in the same process as they do not use the same version of the CLR.

i have created a dotet2.0 component that uses dotnet1.1 assemblies and it works great.
(the xml-componet of http://mygeneration.sourceforge.net/ )

My dotnet1.1 dll improves the base xsd-dataset-codegenerator

On machines that have dotnet 2.0 and 1.1 installed it generates a dotnet1.1 dataset from a dotnet2.0 application

On machines that have dotnet 2.0 but no dot 1.1 it generates a dotnet2.0 dataset.

precondition to make this working:

the api-s referenced by the dotnet1.1 componet must exist in dotnet2 as well (at least the same signature)

the classlibrary dlls must be refereced as "Specific Version=False"

Comment: So you are running in Framework 2 only, not mixing frameworks at all

Comment: @Cobusve: the main app (dotnet2.0) uses a dotnet2.0-plugin dll that in turn uses a dotnet1.1 dll

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get quite a thorough answer from Joshua Goodman from Microsoft. Here is the just of it :

*This is a complex topic.  Over time, we’ve learned more about the difficulties and complexities of compatibility, and changed the behavior of the Framework in different versions.  In addition, we’ve had to make some very hard tradeoffs between things like allowing code to run on a particular version of the Framework, and risking compatibility if it wasn’t designed for that version.*

*You write:
What I struggle to understand is how deriving a 3.5 Class from a 1.1 actually works. As I understand you cannot run  an application in more than 1 framework at the same time, which means the 1.1 class will then be running in CLR 2, although it was not tested/compiled for CLR 2 (it was after all targeted for 1.1?).   It seems like the framework is feeding the 1.1 code to the V2 CLR which quite happily consumes it, but there are a number of breaking changes which you should be aware of then.*

*You are correct – we run the 1.1 version against the V2 CLR, and there is risk in doing that.  We’ve worked to minimize that risk, but if your 1.1 class takes a dependency on 1.1 behavior, it may break.*

*You write:
As far as I can gather the framework does not work quite like COM where a surrogate process is started when required and the class would be instantiated out of process, which would have allowed the Framework 1.1 part of the code to run in the V1 CLR and the new code in the V2 CLR.*

*In .NET 4, we added our in-process Side-by-Side option.  This allows us to run CLR V2 and CLR V4 in the same process, in certain circumstances (particularly COM objects).  But the behavior does not apply for library derivation – crossing CLR boundaries for calls to libraries would be incredibly complex and probably slow.  You may want to read this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx Note that V2 and V1.1 cannot run in the same process.*

*You write:
The core of the problem is that we did an analysis of the breaking changes from Framework 1.1 to Framework 2 and a decision was taken that it was too risky to convert everything to Framework 2 at this stage due to these. The guys then tried to do the new front-ends in Framework 2, but leave the legacy code running in Framework 1.1. I took one look at this and said that this cannot be done as ALL the code will be running in Framework 2 in any case?*

*You are correct – the code will all run on Framework 2.  In fact, the situation is worse (or better) than you describe.  For V1.1 and V2, we have roll-forward behavior.  If you run your code on a machine with V2 installed, we ALWAYS run on V2, even if the application is a V1.1 app, and V1.1 is available on the machine.  There are some good reasons for this (mainly involving COM activation), but it’s risky.  That’s why we introduced the in-process Side-by-side behavior in V4 (which does not necessitate the roll forward behavior.)  I think you might be able to disable this roll-forward behavior with a config file, though I’d have to double check.*

*One more thing to note --  when running a 1.1 component on the 2.0 CLR we will automatically upgrade all framework references to the 2.0 versions of those assemblies. This means that the specific version of System.Windows.Forms.dll referenced by the project has no effect on what is loaded: we always choose the version that matches the version of the CLR the assembly is loaded in .*